# Why is the rectified Gaussian distribution neither discrete nor continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

It's been a few years, so I suspect that I'm forgetting my Lebesgue Integration, but here goes. [As Wikipedia shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectified_Gaussian_distribution),  the rectified Gaussian distribution has a probability density function. From inspection, this density function is obviously not continuous and therefore obviously not absolutely continuous.

However, every definition that I can recall for what make a probability distribution continuous refers to its **distribution** function. As Wikipedia has only given us the density, how can we conclude from this information that the rectified Gaussian distribution is not continuous? In fact, even though the use of the Dirac function should make this obvious, how can we even conclude that it is not discrete?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, note that the PDF has a point mass at $x=0$, so the  CDF has a corresponding jump at $x=0$. This distribution is neither continuous nor discrete, but has properties of both.

Comment: @MPW Very good intuition, but I could do with seeing the rigor. It's not obvious that a point mass causes the distribution function to jump. I believe that you've understood the question perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectified Gaussian distribution has all negative values reset to $0$ so it is a mixture of a discrete distribution (with probability concentrated at $0$) and a continuous distribution (a normal distribution truncated below $0$).

The distribution function is discontinuous at $0$ since $\mathbb P(X<0)=0$ while $\mathbb P(X\le 0)=\Phi(-\mu / \sigma) >0$.  So there is no probability density at $0$.

The distribution is not discrete since its support is all non-negative real numbers and the distribution function is continuous and strictly increasing for all positive reals.

Comment: There's definitely a probability density at 0. Just substitute x=0 in to the density function.

Comment: @J.Mini If there was a density everywhere you could integrate it across all real values to get $1$.  But you cannot, so there is not, and the place where you have problems is at $x=0$

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the distribution function is discontinuous at 0. As you've just pointed out, 0 has no density.

Comment: @J.Mini $\mathbb P(X<0)=0$ while $\mathbb P(X\le 0)=\Phi(-\mu / \sigma) >0$ so there is a discontinuity in the distribution function at $0$. I have added this to the answer.